# java Plugins working in Android Studio Project, but not in Unity

Tags: java, android, maven, unity-game-engine

I am using [Moquette](https://github.com/technocreatives/moquette) Android Broker. So, compiling the maven lib and using the jars within an Android Studio project works fine!

```
import org.eclipse.moquette.server.Server;

Server server = new Server();
server.startServer();
```

So thats the java code, in Unity I am wrapping the function calls like:

```
AndroidJavaClass server = new AndroidJavaClass("org.eclipse.moquette.server.Server");
server.Call("startServer");
```

However, The Unity project is building without any Error, but when I start I do not get any Error and also no Debug output of the call (neither from Unity, not from the java plugins). So Unity is not complaining but also the java code is not executed i guess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AndroidJavaObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.html) instead of [AndroidJavaClass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html), like this:

```
AndroidJavaObject server = new AndroidJavaObject("org.eclipse.moquette.server.Server");
server.Call("startServer");
```

If you wanted to invoke a static method, you can use [AndroidJavaClass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html), but then you would have to use the [CallStatic(...)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic.html) method.

```
AndroidJavaClass server = new AndroidJavaClass("org.eclipse.moquette.server.Server");
server.CallStatic("startServer");
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem